# Name of image and way to generate it

Tags: php, identicon

I frequently see the following kind of images on many websites (on StackOverflow for example).

What is this kind of image called and how do I generate it? (preferably in PHP)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just google 'gravatar'.... (as an alternative to what u wanted)

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate question, but here is more to read about: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon

Using GD library and this source http://sourceforge.net/projects/identicons/ for PHP

Quote from wiki, for those who are lazy to open the link:

> An Identicon is a visual representation of a hash value, usually of an IP address, that serves to identify a user of a computer system as a form of avatar while protecting the users' privacy. The original Identicon was a 9-block graphic, and the representation has been extended to other graphic forms by third parties.

Comment: why do you answer when you know its a dupicate ? O.o . Just flag it.

Comment: well i cant flag this as the duplicate as it must be from "stackoverflow" domain, but its from meta.stackoverflow :D meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/17443/how-is-the-default-user-avatar-generated

Comment: I had no idea that such images were called 'identicon', so I had no way to figure out if that question has already been asked.

Comment: No problem, we all make mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

You can a try this code something similar to your above query.
[Not a direct answer though]

```
<?php
$Width = 64;
$Height = 64;

$Image = imagecreate($Width, $Height);
for($Row = 1; $Row <= $Height; $Row++) {
    for($Column = 1; $Column <= $Width; $Column++) {
        $Red = mt_rand(0,255);
        $Green = mt_rand(0,255);
        $Blue = mt_rand(0,255);
        $Colour = imagecolorallocate ($Image, $Red , $Green, $Blue);
    }
}

header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($Image);
?>
```

Generates a random color each and every time like this.

[image]